# WooCommerce and letters in Postcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a WordPress site using WooCommerce. Recently Canadian customers wanted to place an order but WC doesn't allow for letters in the post code. A Canadian post code may be R2C or A1A rather than the us standard ##### or #####-####. How can I set it up so WooCommerce allows for post/zip codes with letters rather than just numbers?

Comment: is ther no option to add region/country there ?

Comment: I can select a country at checkout and even a province but when I add the postal code I get an error saying it please enter a valid zip code. It looks like it won't take just a 3 character zip. I have to have a 6 character zip. For example, M4B didn’t work but M4B 1B3 did. Is there a way to make it so it accepts a 3 character zip?

Comment: Did you check this link https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-shipping-zones/